# HTML 5's <picture> lazy load (without jquery)

Tags: javascript, css, html

I've programmed a small lightbox for viewing images on my website. To keep the loading process fast I would like to "lazy load" the fullsize image. At the moment browsers always load the preview (test.jpg?size=520px) and the fullsize image (test.jpg).

Is there any simple solution to prevent browsers from loading the fullsize image until the image is clicked?

- The website is only using minimal javascript - but I found no "no javascript" solution. Additionally I prefer a solution that doesn't require large html strings inside the .js file that will be added on mouse click.
- Most lazy load scripts change only the attribute key inside the image tag. However, with HTML 5 this is now longer a useful approach. Maybe it is possible to change the `<picture>` tag (`<picture>` <<>> `<picture-disabled>`) and prefetch the full size image?

HTML:

```
<div class="imagecc">
        <picture onclick="lightboxshow('test004.jpg')">
            <source type="image/webp" srcset="test004.webp?size=520px">
            <img src="test.jpg?size=520px" alt="...">
        </picture>
        <p class="imgcaption">...</p>
</div>
<div id="test004.jpg" class="imageccbox" onclick="lightboxclose(this)">
    <div class="imageccboxpicture">
        <picture>
            <source type="image/webp" srcset="test004.webp">
            <img src="test.jpg">
        </picture>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.imageccbox {
       display: none;
       position: fixed;
       z-index: 9999;
       top: 0; left: 0;
       width: 100%;
       height: 100%;
       background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.9), rgba(255,255,255,1));
       text-align: center;}
.imageccbox:target {
        background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
        display: block;
        outline: none;}
.imageccbox:target > .imageccboxpicture {opacity: 1.0;}
.imageccboxpicture {
        margin-top: 5%;
        opacity: 0.4;
        transition: opacity 500ms linear;
        cursor: none;}
```

JavaScript:

```
function lightboxshow(object) {
        var imageccbox = document.getElementById(object);
        imageccbox.style.display='block';
        setTimeout(function() {imageccbox.getElementsByClassName("imageccboxpicture")[0].style.opacity = 1.0;}, 25);
         window.location.hash = object;}
```

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't a way to lazyload with CSS. If the image is included in the <src> of the img/picture tag, it will be loaded in immediately.

The reason is that CSS is not a dynamic language. The only way to defer loading things in with CSS, would be with Javascript/jQuery.

Comment: Here is a CSS only fiddle with lazy full size image load. And it's backwards compatible down to IE6. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/LgHcN/)

Comment: @BekimBacaj Your solution requires the full image file name in the CSS (background: url). I think therefore aardrian's solution seems to be better suited for dynamic web pages

Comment: No, it doesn't. The demo was forced for using live but completely alien, external sources of images, with absolute paths for it to be able to demonstrate its functionality, but they are completely unnecessary for images that are yours and reside in your own domain - but you should know that. Relative paths are very short. And it was for illustrating to what can be done with css1.2 only. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using the [`<template>` element](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/template/). It's just a part of web components.

Essentially you stuff any content in `<template>` that you do not want the browser to load, and then move the content when you want it to be loaded. You make that change `onload`, or `onclick`, or whatever other event you like. Either way, it's not a lot of JavaScript to do and you don't need any libraries.

Take a look at this tutorial: [Quick trick: using template to delay loading of images](https://www.christianheilmann.com/2015/09/08/quick-trick-using-template-to-delay-loading-of-images/).

Older browsers that don't support the tag just won't get the lazy load benefit, so there is a nice progressive enhancement bonus there as well.

Another reference: http://webcomponents.org/articles/introduction-to-template-element/

Comment: This is the perfect solution. Thank you! It's working perfectly in Chrome and Firefox. Edge is supposed [to support it also](http://caniuse.com/#search=template) - but it is not working yet... :-)

Answer (score 1):

As Charlie said, the only way to do this is with JavaScript.

One solution is to remove the `src` attribute from the `<img>` tag and only add it when the image is clicked:

```
function lightboxshow(object) {
    var imageccbox = document.getElementById(object);

    var img = imageccbox.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
    img.setAttribute('src', 'test.jpg');

    imageccbox.style.display='block';
    setTimeout(function() {imageccbox.getElementsByClassName("imageccboxpicture")[0].style.opacity = 1.0;}, 25);
     window.location.hash = object;
}
```

Edit: please see aardrian response as that template solution seems way more interesting!